How to use Word VBA Code to Clear All on Clipboard?
How to use VBA Code to Clear All on Clipboard?
Recently Copy and Paste stopped functioning, the Copy simply did not register on the Clipboard.
Then a few key strokes later, the Copy feature would return again,
Other times it would return only after operating some other macros, when that didn't work, just normal application use caused the problem to reset or go away, not sure how.
Note: Although some times PopUp "No enough memory" or "Clipboard Currently being used" unlocking freeze on Clipboard Copy was random, sometimes did NOT go away after closing apps or about 10 internet browser tabs.
Have tried answer to
How to Clear Office Clipboard with VBA
But that comes up with error message “User Defined Type not Defined”
I have several Macros in Word utilising clip board.
I found that “Clear Clipboard” some times but not always reactivating the Copy function, but can’t find a way to activate via VBA. Some of VBA script on line were incredible complex series of 3 Subs & Functions.
The same could be achieved via Windows: this works as a Shortcut file:
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c "echo off | clip"
OR
This works from Command prompt:
cmd.exe /c "echo off | clip"
I tried to use this routine for opening Word Docs but I did not get it to work on a Shortcut executing a CMD line:
Sub OpenDoc()
    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = "c:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\Test PM.docm"    'change to path of your file
    If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then    'First we check if document exists at all at given location
        Documents.Open strFile
    End If
End Sub

Documents.Open doesn't seem to be relevant because the file is a cmd instruction not a document.
The Clipboard Macro worked well until recently, copied off some professional site:
Function Clipboard(Optional StoreText As String) As String
'PURPOSE: Read/Write to Clipboard
'Source: ExcelHero.com (Daniel Ferry)
Dim x As Variant
'Store as variant for 64-bit VBA support
x = StoreText
'Create HTMLFile Object
With CreateObject("htmlfile")
With .parentWindow.clipboardData
Select Case True
Case Len(StoreText)
'Write to the clipboard
.setData "text", x
Case Else
'Read from the clipboard (no variable passed through)
Clipboard = .GetData("text")
End Select
End With
End With
End Function
Requests: assistance with any of the above alternatives starting at the top, the most preferred:

what could be causing Word Copy to Clipboard to fail?
what is the best way to prevent routines possibly intervene when they are not asked to? There are very few Public Functions and no live Event Functions, I cancelled both of the latter to rule them out as possible causes, so it remains a mystery to me
Can there be an automated switching off or terminate all background routines when Copy function is activated? and/or
although it does not always work: how to get Clipboard “Clear All” in Macro format, half baked attempts above.
Note that as a VBA novice I won’t understand shortcut answers but am able to copy’n’paste code that works. When the copy function works that is!
Thanks in advance :)


Is your root problem with manual copy/paste, or do you have VBA code which is failing on copy/paste operations?  I've never seen any post here about needing to clear the clipboard completely to fix these types of problems...

Thx Tim, Cntl+c or right click "Copy" neither puts text on clipboard. But intermittent, no clear cause and effect, some times when no macros or other features had been used since last use of Copy'n'Paste only seconds beforehand.
Macro alternative doesnt load to Clipbd either  but still Debug Print selection but PopUp "No enough memory" until apps closed:
Sub Copy_Ctlc()
'   CDuv 1May24 attempt to override using shortcut Cntl + c
Dim SelnCop As String
If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then
Selection.Copy
End If
SelnCop = Selection
Debug.Print "Copy_Ctlc = "; SelnCop
End Sub

thanks Jonsson, definitely no macros running, that is one of the first ports of call. Have updated "Ans my own Question" problem disappeared after closing Time Sheet Excel file with Macros jamming up on process line where Clipboard was used.

Appears to be resolved: "Clipboard jammed up" problem disappeared after closing Time Sheet Excel file with Macros jamming up on process line where Clipboard was used. The problem only occurred when that file is open. This was only after I was experimenting trying to get "Workbook Event to Close file on save" if Mac address was NOT the one in my macro. I had performed extensive trial and error on the latter, then tried annulling all the code to those attempts, but could not isolate the cause affecting Clipboard, so I just reverted to an earlier back of the Time Sheet file. In turn, Word Clipboard seems normal, so far about 2 hours use with no problem, previously recurring at least once every 5 minutes.
I would still be interested to know answers to questions 2 to 4. above on how to isolate this type of problem and how to manage halt background operations through VBA, but not so significant with no specific problem to apply the solutions to, at present anyway.
Thanks for your attention folks.
